# How to insert CTE output to temp table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, ddl

In Oracle, I am trying to insert the output of a CTE into a temp table using below code but it is giving error. I don't want to create the temp table in advance, it should be created with the column names and data types from CTE dynamically.

```
with cte as (
select ORDER_ID, STATUS_ID, CALL_DATE, SHIP_DATE,
       UPDATE_USER_ID,  UPDATE_TIMESTAMP,
       row_number() over(partition by ORDER_ID order by update_timestamp desc) as rowno 
FROM ORDER_HISTORY
where ORDER_ID in (1001,1002, 1003)
)
create table temp_recent_order as
select * from cte where rowno=1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Replace the order for `create table` statement like below :

```
create table temp_recent_order as
with cte as (
select ORDER_ID,
       STATUS_ID,
       CALL_DATE,
       SHIP_DATE,
       UPDATE_USER_ID,
       UPDATE_TIMESTAMP,
       row_number() over(partition by ORDER_ID order by update_timestamp desc) as rowno
  from ORDER_HISTORY
 where ORDER_ID in (1001, 1002, 1003)
)
select * from cte where rowno=1;
```